# .htaccess language redirects with SEO-friendly URLs

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirects

How do I setup my *.htaccess* file to detect several languages, and redirect them to specific SEO-friendly URLs?

Basically every URL needs to go to `index.php?lang=(...)`.

So, for **English** language detection `http://mysite.com` has to go to `http://mysite.com/en/` (`index.php?lang=en`).

My *.htaccess* as of now (not working):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:HOST} http://mysite.com/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/es/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|de|nl|fr|es)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Whats the output of `RewriteLog` ?

Comment: I think the question is more appropriate for [webmaster.se].

Comment: @DanFromGermany I can't seem to get the RewriteLog working. `apache_error.log` says `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here`, even though I specified `RewriteLog "htaccesslogs.txt"`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Can I just move this question to Webmasters?

Comment: Click the flag link under the question, chose the "Other" option. State that the post be move to [webmaster.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there. Drop the very first `RewriteCond` (as it's not required and won't match ever) and add a trailing `/` to your last `RewriteRule` since you're redirecting with them.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/es/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|de|nl|fr|es)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: "This webpage has a redirect loop" for me. with a simple index.php (has only html content), nothing else in .htaccess. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for language and country parameters. This supports any language:

```
#www.country.com/index.html  becomes www.country.com/index.php
#www.country.com/fr/index.html  becomes www.country.com/index.php?language=fr
#www.country.com/ca/fr/index.html  becomes www.country.com/index.php?country=ca&language=fr

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/([a-zA-Z]{2,3})/index\.html$ index.html?country=$1&language=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2,3})/index\.html$ index.html?language=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Answers here are required to be in English only. Please see the edits I made for you [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/57544/revisions) to help with your answers in the future.